# flex mobile - fastest way to load local file?

Tags: air, flex4.5, flex-mobile, actionscript-3

I'm gonna load local files in Flex mobile environment.

there are so many ways to load local files in Flex mobile.

`URLLoader(URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY)`, `Loader`, `URLStream`, `FileStream` etc.

so, what will be the fastest way to load local files in Flex mobile? (android)

I'll be waiting nice answer. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about "local" files, so there is no internet connection required I assume?

In that case have a look at the File class > http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html

Then use FileStream to read the local file.